# Flutter get bluetooth name connected device

Tags: flutter, dart

How to get the name of a connected device in flutter?
I need only the name of the device connected to the smartphone ie: "Toyota car"

P.S. For Andorid if it makes some difference

Answer (score 0):

Could use [flutter_blue](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue) package

In the [example](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue/example) it's shown how to get device name.

Or could simply:

```
// Start scanning
flutterBlue.startScan(timeout: Duration(seconds: 4));

// Listen to scan results
var subscription = flutterBlue.scanResults.listen((results) {
    // do something with scan results
    for (ScanResult r in results) {
        print('${r.device.name} found! rssi: ${r.rssi}');
    }
});

// Stop scanning
flutterBlue.stopScan();
```